# Nesting modules outside of module declaration

Tags: ruby, module, nested, activesupport

I want something like `A::B::C.nesting #=> [A::B::C, A::B, A]` but outside of these modules' declarations... How can I get this? ActiveSupport is enabled. Thanks.

Comment: Hm... What's wrong with this question??

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can I get this? I have a module, and I want to get its namespaces. Thanks.

Comment: Write that as a question, not as a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Module
  def nesting
    a = inspect.split("::")
    a.length.downto(1).to_a.map{|l| const_get(a[0, l].join("::"))}
  end
end
```

or

```
class Module
  def nesting
    s = inspect
    s.count(":")./(2).downto(0).to_a.map{|l| const_get(s[/[^:]+(?:::[^:]+){#{l}}/])}
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks very much! P. S. I thought to do it without metaprogramming :-)

Comment: There is no built in way.